# Command requires missing /run on read-only filsystem

Tags: encryption, embedded-linux, dm-crypt, squashfs

I am trying to run a command (`cryptsetup`) on an embedded system using squashfs. It requires `/run` but that directory does not exist, and I cannot create it since it is read-only.

I have an ASUS router with asuswrt-merlin installed (`linux-2.6`). I have installed [Entware](https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin/wiki/Entware) to download cryptsetup, and I am trying to use it to encrypt an attached hard disk:

`$ cryptsetup --key-size 256 luksFormat /dev/sdb1`

Which results in:

```
...
Enter passphrase for /dev/sdb1:
Verify passphrase:
Locking aborted. The locking path /run/cryptsetup is unusable (not a directory or missing).
Failed to acquire device lock.
Cannot format device /dev/sdb1 in use.
```

I don't see anything in `cryptsetup`'s man pages to force or skip/change the lockfile directory and so am stuck.

The [guide](https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin/wiki/LUKS-Encrypted-USB-Drive-HOWTO) I am following to set this up does not mention this issue at all, but is somewhat outdated.

Is there a way to fake this directory, or some argument to `cryptsetup` that I can use to bypass it, or some other option?

Note that `/var/run` exists but since it's a read-only filesystem I cannot symlink it. And since `/run` doesn't exist I can't (as far as I know) mount a tmpfs to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got this option with `cryptsetup`, but it sounds risky.

```
   --disable-locks
          Disable lock protection for metadata on disk.  This option is
          valid only for LUKS2 and ignored for other formats.

          WARNING: Do not use this option unless you run cryptsetup in a
          restricted environment where locking is impossible to perform
          (where /run directory cannot be used).
```

The other way out of this is a `chroot` - and if your router has a USB port, you can connect a 4GB flash drive and maybe have enough to space to copy over everything `cryptsetup` wants.  Though at that point you may just setup a Debian `chroot` on it and then you'll have all the tools you need to do anything you want (as long as you keep the chroot environment updated).

Comment: You know I try and research stuff to make decent questions and there's literally the answer right there but the die.net man pages did not list that as an option! Thanks!